# What the Scala submission file would look like when submitting a job to Condor?

Tags: scala, submission, condor

I tried to submit a job to Condor with a jar file that I compiled from Scala using

```
sbt package
```

It's just a basic HelloWorld program. Then, I wasn't sure how the submission file would look like. I tried a few combinations to mimic what I did in java

```
universe                = Scala
executable              = Hello.jar
arguments               = Hello
jar_files               = Hello.jar
log                     = hello.log
error                   = hello.err
output                  = hello-$(Process).txt
Queue 1
```

raised

```
ERROR: I don't know about the 'Scala' universe.
```

I also tried

```
universe                = java
```

and

```
universe                = Vanilla
```

but no luck. Any assistance will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This is a pretty late response, but the following configuration file worked for me, building on the hint [given here](https://blog.ajduke.in/2013/05/31/various-ways-to-run-scala-code/) about using the java interpreter to run scala code. The blog basically says that the following line would run a scala class called Hello:

```
java -cp $SCALA_HOME/lib/scala-library.jar;. Hello
```

I had to copy the scala-library.jar to the working directory for the config file to work.

```
universe       = java
executable     = Compute.class
jar_files      = scala-library.jar
arguments      = Compute
output         = Compute.output
error          = Compute.error
queue
```

Hope this helps. Haven't tried out for any serious scala programs though.